# Silverlight 4 calls SQL server query command

Tags: silverlight

My Silverlight 4 application has a DataGrid control which needs to display data rows from SQL server query command (e.g. SELECT * FROM TABLE...).  Is there any solution?  Do I need use WCF or ADO?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description of "DataGrid control which needs to display data rows from SQL server query command" you want to use RIA services.

- Create a RIA services Silverlight project (or enable RIA services on your existing project)
- Create an Entity Framework model referencing your SQL server table
- Create a Domain service that uses your EF model
- After building the project you will then be able to see your tables in the Data Sources window
- From the Data Sources window you can directly drag a grid, representing that table, onto a page. This will create a DomainDataSource as well as the DataGrid and wire it all up for you.
- The only bit you will need to add is paging.

Here is some more information about this process: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707376(v=vs.91).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707376%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)

I know it sounds like a lot or work, but once you get used to the steps it is all pretty simple (and makes the draggy-droppy stuff work really well).

Comment: Thanks for help that it works with the EF model and 'WCF Data Service'.  But I need to assign the table & field name at compile time.  Is there any way to assign table/field names at runtime to LINQ query?

Comment: @CHI KUO TANG: You don't have to use Linq and EF for the server side. Once the Domain service is connected you can replace the server side of the RIA service with your own code (including RAW SQL calls constructed from strings).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Now I used both EDM and Domain service (WCF RIA Service) to get some data.  But I only use the basic context->GetComstersQuery() like call to get whole data in table.  Would you tell how to use RAW SQL calls from string on EDM/Domain server as you mentioned in your previous reply?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CHI KUO TANG: There are 2 issues here. 1. If you just want to filter RIA services data, just apply your LINQ filter to the Query on the domain service before calling load. The filter will be serialized to the server. 2. If you want to execute raw SQL code, that returns arbitrary columns you will need to have a return type that can handle that. This would however open a security hole in your app if any old SQL could be executed. Better off with filtered RIA queries and fixed shape results.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for reply and it's closer.  I tried to use 'WHERE' on linq but it is not recognized.  Should I use 'LINQ Dynamic Query Library'? Or there is some other easy way?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight cannot, at the moment, access databases like Sql Server or Oracle directly.

To access data you have to use some form of service as a gateway to your data.

Pure WCF is an option.

You should also take a look at WCF RIA Services.

This a good link to see what else is available.
http://wildermuth.com/2010/07/08/State_of_Data_Access_in_Silverlight_4

You can also take a look on project Agatha-rrsl.
http://code.google.com/p/agatha-rrsl/

The above are all free.

There are non free alternatives too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I do use a 'Web Service' to get sql query data but on Silverlight side it only allow 'array', 'List' or 'dictionary'.  I need to pass 'List of DbDataRecord' back to Silverlight but it seems Silverlight did not allow 'DbDataRecord' namespace 'system.data.common' be used.  So I could only pass back jagged array.  Is there any way to pass list of DbDataRecord back to Silverlight app?  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. I never tried anyways and I don't think it's a good idea. This class does not exist in Silverlight. You could try using Json.Net to serialize the data and send it over. Just remember that any data going to Silverlight must be serializable in some form.